# Can't use npm to install nebular for angular project

Tags: nebular

I don't know what's happening to the collection for nebular, but it doesn't install, even on manual mode. Is this a recurring problem with the lib or there's something wrong with my npm install?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you use :

```
 ng add @nebular/theme
```

or

```
npm i --save-dev
```